# Numpy: Smart way to clip array values and carry leftover to next

Tags: python, numpy

Because of an underlying datastructure there is a maximum for values in my array.

Is there a smart way in numpy to clip the array and carry the leftover to next elements?

(I'm simlifying this to a 1D array here)

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: array = np.arange(10, 1, -1)

In [3]: rest = 0

In [4]: array
Out[4]: array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2])

In [5]: for i, x in enumerate(array):
   ...:     tmp = array[i] + rest
   ...:     if tmp > 8:
   ...:         array[i] = 8
   ...:         rest = tmp - 8
   ...:     elif tmp <= 8:
   ...:         array[i] = tmp
   ...:         rest = 0
   ...:

In [6]: array
Out[6]: array([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2])
```

This works, but is there a smarter way to do this in numpy, that also supports more dimensions? Ex. an array of vectors. When combining them, the path will not be the same, but they will sum up to the same.

Comment: Do one clip at max 8, subtract the original from the clip, then do a cumsum and add

Comment: @Reinderien You would need to make sure you only add the difference to terms that weren't clipped and keep repeating the clipping until the difference array sums to 0 (or make sure you're adding the remainder to terms without pushing them over the 8 limit).

Comment: I can't get this working. Subtracted is `[-2, -1, 0, ...]` and cumsum will be `[-2, -3, -3, ...]`. All but the first in cumsum is -3, when adding this to array (or clipped), I end up with `[ 8,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0, -1]`.

Comment: @kristus What should be the result of `[1,1,7,8,12]`? Note, there last number of array is greater than `8`

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: @AndrejKesely: In my case it would be `[1, 1, 7, 8, 8]`. But it is possible to extend the array as well, or place the excess in front. Ex. `[1, 4, 8, 8, 8]` 
@jared: No, it don't need to be sorted

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the space left in each cell, i.e. what we could add to get the maximum cell value. Calculate the total excess, i.e. the sum of values exceeding the maximum cell value that need to be redistributed.

Then create a Boolean array indicating which cells need to be changed. Derive the index of the last cell that needs to be changed.

Fill the cells that need to be changed with the maximum cell value. Now we just need to correct the last changed cell, because here a smaller value may be required to reach the correct sum overall.

We always fill up the array from left to right. If it cannot be done, because the sum is too large, return the array with all cells filled to the max.

```py
import numpy as np

def redistribute(a, cell_max):
    full = np.full_like(a, cell_max)
    if a.sum() >= full.sum():
        return full
    
    space_left = np.maximum((full - a), 0)
    excess = np.where(a > cell_max, a - cell_max, 0).sum()  
    
    needs_change = space_left.cumsum() < excess
    last_change = np.argmin(needs_change)
    
    result = np.where(needs_change, full, np.minimum(a, cell_max))
    result[last_change] += a.sum() - result.sum()
    return result
    
    
redistribute(np.arange(10, 1, -1), 8)
# -> array([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2])
```

For higher dimensions, you could unravel the array, apply this function and reshape.